# Why trajectories approach to origin tangent to the slower direction?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, differentiation, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I am reading non-linear dynamics from Strogartz. Suppose, I have two solutions of a non linear system: $x(t) = x_0e^{at}$ and $y(t) = y_0e^{-t}$, where $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Now it is clear that,for $a<-1$ and $t\rightarrow \infty$, $x(t)$ decays rapidly than $y(t)$. Strogatz has written that *"Trajectories approach the origin tangent to the slower direction."* I can't understand why this will happen. Please give a concrete explanation.

[image: Trajectories for $a<-1$]

Comment: For a < -1, X decays more rapidly that y, and the trajectory approaches the origin tangent to the x axis. For other values of a, y decays more rapidly and the trajectory is tangent to the y axis.

Comment: No, the trajectories (for $a<-1$) are approaching to the origin tangent to $y$-axis (which is the slower direction). _My question is why trajectories will approach to origin tangent to slower direction?_ @mmesser314

Comment: @SubhajitMishra - I think you misunderstood mmesser314's answer because they were correct.  The value of $a$ determines which, $x(t)$ or $y(t)$, function is the slower of the two.

Answer (score 1):

If the $y$ position decays to zero faster than the $x$ position, then there will be a time $t$ when $y$ is very close to zero while $x$ is still much bigger than zero.

It immediately follows that with $y$ (almost) equal to zero and $x$ still decreasing, the particle will approach along the $x$ axis.

Which is just re-stating what your book said.

You could convince yourself mathematically by taking the derivative of $x$ and $y$ with respect to $t$, then evaluating their ratio, since

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\partial y/\partial t}{\partial x/\partial t}$$